# why Printstream sticks suddenly?

Tags: java

I'm Writing a program that runs another java program. I have a method which is responsible for providing inputs(for the second program) by using a printStream object. The problem is that after calling the method for some times, say 60 times, it suddenly sticks. Could anyone help ?

here's the method:

```
 private void runProcess(String command, int test_number) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    try(PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(pro.getOutputStream());) {
        for (String testcase_input : testcase_inputs) {
            printStream.println(testcase_input);
            printStream.flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the other process reading its standard input?

Comment: yes it is, and it works fine for many times being called

Comment: And nothing causes it to stop reading the input (e.g. an exception)? Because your problem sounds like the buffer is filling up.

Comment: no , it continues processing